# unable to close tab after log-out in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, firefox

i tired to find out way to close tab after log out in Firefox.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
window.open('','_self'); 
window.close();
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');
</script>
```

working in other browser but problem in Firefox. i need to close tab when signout/logout attempt.

Comment: i also tried by adding this link 
<a href="javascript:self.close()">Close Window</a>
but Console error: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox will not allow you to close windows or tabs that a user opened.

Most financial sites for this reason will ask users to click a button and open a new window.
you can do this with `window.open`. Store the handle returned by that and use it to close the window you opened. The user may have many other tabs open in that window.

Refer: [`window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.close?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.close)

This is how you close a window that you open.

```
var openedWindow;

function openWindow()
{
  openedWindow = window.open('moreinfo.htm');
}
function closeOpenedWindow()
{
  openedWindow.close();
}
```